# Dart RegExp not returning matches

Tags: dart

I have a tested regular expression to split `,` delimited phrases in a string, except where the `,` is in brackets.

Testing the regular expression with this string in https://regex101.com/r/COMj2b/1 with ECMAScript flavour gives desired matches. No matches are printed in my Dart version.

Any guidance much appreciated!

```
void main() {
  String s = """Joe's Jazz Band (Ensemble), Fred Dagg (Guitar), Tommy Tucker (Horn, Clarinet), The Pied Piper (Whistle)""";
  RegExp re = RegExp(r'([^,(]*\([^)]*\))*[^,]*(,|$)');

  List li = s.split(re);
  print('$li');
}
```

My Dart code prints `[,,,]`.

I expected it to print:
`['Joe's Jazz Band (Ensemble)', 'Fred Dagg (Guitar)', 'Tommy Tucker (Horn, Clarinet)', 'The Pied Piper (Whistle)']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[split](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/String/split.html) does not return the matches but splits the string at matches of pattern and returns a list of substrings.

Supposing that the separator is a `)` bracket followed by zero or more spaces and a comma, this works with split:

```
void main() {
  String s = """Joe's Jazz Band (Ensemble), Fred Dagg (Guitar), Tommy Tucker (Horn, Clarinet), The Pied Piper (Whistle)""";
  RegExp re = RegExp(r'\)[ \t]*,');

  Iterable li = s.split(re).map((item) => item.endsWith(")") ? item.trim() : "$item)".trim());

  li.forEach((item) => print('$item'));

}
```

Note that it is necessary to add a `)` at the last splitted element.
The `trim()` is not necessary at less you want to remove leading and trailing whitespaces.

Comment: So basically we pass regex for char/string that splits original string?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In this case it rightly returns `[,,,]`

Comment: @altdona thanks for your response but I still don't get it. Also Dartpad reports an error in the RE: Uncaught exception:
FormatException: Illegal RegExp pattern (SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\)[ t\]*,/: Unterminated character class)
\)[ t\]*,

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo: I wrote t\ instead of `\t` for tabs.

Comment: Presumably I'm not understanding the terminology 'match'. In [,,,] the substrings have 0 length - so why was this correct?

Comment: Your regexp returns 4 captured groups (4 matches) but it capture also the comma separator: the first match for example is `Joe's Jazz Band (Ensemble),`. So `split` returns a list of void strings.

Comment: I didn't pick up the RE error either :-) Your code works with my example but it'll take more effort for me to understand what's happening. Also the RE doesn't handle cases with phrases that don't have any brackets.  So "John Baker" should be separated from "Fred Dagg (Guitar)" in the string "Joe's Jazz Band (Ensemble), John Baker, Fred Dagg (Guitar), Tommy Tucker (Horn, Clarinet), The Pied Piper (Whistle)"

Comment: Ok, I had a very basic misunderstanding of 'match' and 'group' and incorrect expectation of split. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As said @attdona split doesn't return matches, so if you want to get matches, use something like that:

```
void main() {
  String s = """Joe's Jazz Band (Ensemble), Fred Dagg (Guitar), Tommy Tucker (Horn, Clarinet), The Pied Piper (Whistle)""";
  RegExp re = RegExp(r'([^,(]*\([^)]*\))*[^,]*(,|$)');

  List l = re.allMatches(s).toList();
  List<String> li = new List();
  for(Match e in l) {
    li.add(e.group(0));
  }

  print('$li');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Denis Sablukov. Your code works best for my needs. (Unfortunately I can't accept both answers.)